# Comparing a single value to multiple values from arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, web-scraping

My code looks like this:

```py
import requests
import re
import mechanize
import urllib
import json

htmltext = urllib.urlopen("https://www.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=BCDBTC&interval=4h")

data = json.load(htmltext)

current_price= data[len(data)-1][4]
last_prices= (data[len(data)-2][4],data[len(data)-3][4],data[len(data)-4][4],data[len(data)-5][4],data[len(data)-6][4])
last_volumes= (data[len(data)-2][5],data[len(data)-3][5],data[len(data)-4][5],data[len(data)-5][5],data[len(data)-6][5])
current_volume= data[len(data)-1][5]

print current_price
print last_prices
if current_price > last_prices:
    print "the current price is greater than the last 5"
print current_volume
print last_volumes
if current_volume > last_volumes:
    print "the current volume is higher than the last 5"
```

But my output is this:

```
0.00495600
(u'0.00492500', u'0.00366300', u'0.00332800', u'0.00333800', u'0.00308000')
the current price is greater than the last 5
938.01000000
(u'29687.32500000', u'14740.03800000', u'9366.77400000', u'10324.83200000', u'44953.53400000')
the current volume is higher than the last 5
```

The problem here is the current volume is certainly not greater than the last 5 but it's still printing it out regardless

I'm grabbing data from here
https://www.binance.com/tradeDetail.html?symbol=BCD_BTC

Comment: Why not `data[-2]` instead of `data[len(data)-2]` all over the place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your data are not all converted to numbers, many of them are in string format. To convert them all to floating point numbers, you can use this formula:

```
data = [[float(x) for x in row] for row in data]
```

Next, in the if statement, you are comparing a number with a sequence of numbers. What you want is to compare this number with the largest in the sequence:

```
if current_price > max(last_prices):
    print "the current price is greater than the last 5"
```

Putting it all together:

```
# code to obtain data is the same

PRICE = 4
VOLUME = 5
LAST_ROW = -1

data = [[float(x) for x in row] for row in data]

current_price = data[LAST_ROW][PRICE]
current_volume = data[LAST_ROW][VOLUME]
last_prices = tuple(row[PRICE] for row in data[-6:-1])
last_volumes = tuple(row[VOLUME] for row in data[-6:-1])

print 'current_price =', current_price
print 'current_volume =', current_volume
print 'last_prices =', last_prices
print 'last_volumes =', last_volumes

if current_price > max(last_prices):
    print "the current price is greater than the last 5"

if current_volume > max(last_volumes):
    print "the current volume is higher than the last 5"
```

Comment: `data[-6:-1]` ==> 5 rows immediately before the last, `data[-6:]` ==> last 6 rows